# Controller para generar un docx usando apache poi

Tags: java, netbeans

estaria nacesitando armar el controller para que se me descargue un archivo docx. a continuacion adjunto mi intento de controller y mi service

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/generarWord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public XWPFDocument postGenerarWord(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, Exception {
            XWPFDocument wb = reporteWordSR.main();
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=documento.docx");
            wb.write( response.getOutputStream() );
        return wb;
    }
```

y mi service

```
public class ReporteWordService {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
       public void crear() {
       try {
           FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("documento.docx");
           document.write(output);
           output.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage().toString());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola, cual es el problema ?, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola jorge, aca te dejo mejor formulada la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578729/el-archivo-docx-se-me-descarga-sin-poder-abrir